# Development of the Idea of Homeomorphism?

Tags: topology

How did the historical development of the notion of homeomorphism take place?

At first, I think the most important thing to study were continuous functions and metric structures.

When did the focus of mathematicians shift from metric to open sets?

Comment: This is already answered on Math Overflow, [Homeomorphism historically](https://mathoverflow.net/q/200584). The source is [Moore's paper The evolution of the concept of homeomorphism](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086006000863).